# SSAS Process Default behavior

Tags: ssas

I'm trying to make sense of Process Default behavior on SSAS 2017 Enterprise Edition.

My cube is processed daily in this standard sequence:

1. Loop through 30 dimensions and performing Process Add or Process Update as required.
2. Process approximately 80 partitions for the previous day.
3. Exec a Process Default as the final step.

Everything works just fine, and for the amount of data involved, performs really well. However I have observed that after the process default completes, if I re-run the process default step manually (with no other activity having occurred whatsoever), it will take exactly the same time as the first run.

My understanding was that this step basically scans the cube looking for unprocessed objects and will process any objects found to be unprocessed. Given the flow of dimension processing, and subsequent partition processing, I'd certainly expect some objects to be unprocessed on the first run - particularly aggregations and indexes.

The end to end processing time is around 65 mins, but 10 mins of this is the final process default step.

What would explain this is that if the process default isn't actually finding anything to do, and the elapsed time is the cost of scanning the meta data. Firstly it seems an excessive amount of time, but also if I don't run the step, the cube doesn't come online, which suggests it is definitely doing something.

I've had a trawl through Profiler to try to find events to capture what process default is doing, but I'm not able to find anything that would capture the event specifically. I've also monitored the server performance during the step, and nothing is under any real load.

Any suggestions or clarifications..?